# Reading const variables from a text file for multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, multidimensional-array

I'm new to the community and was referred here by a fellow classmate.

I'm stuck on a school project and was hoping to get some guidance, I don't want someone to complete the code for me, I would just like an idea of what to do...

The question at hand is to create a multidimensional array where your first two numbers of a .txt file are the size of the array.

Example text file:

```
10 5
tom 91 67 84 50 69
suzy 74 78 58 62 64
Peter 55 95 81 77 61
Paul 91 95 92 77 86
Diane 91 54 52 53 92
Emily 82 71 66 68 95
Natalie 97 76 71 88 69
Ben 62 67 99 85 94
Mark 53 61 72 83 73
Anna 64 91 61 53 68
```

So far I have an array with the size of 2 reading from the text file, which I was going to use as my array size. This is what I have so far.

```
const int multiArraySize = 2;
void firstTwoNumbers(int numbers[]){

    int count = 0;             // Loop counter variable
    ifstream inputFile;        // Input file stream object

    // Open the file.
    inputFile.open("grades.txt");

    // Read the numbers from the file into the array.
    while (count < multiArraySize && inputFile >> numbers[count])
        count++;

    // Close the file.
    inputFile.close();
}
```

And in my main I have this

```
int numbers[multiArraySize];
firstTwoNumbers(numbers);
int multiArray[numbers[0]][numbers[1]];
```

Thank you in advance for your help Stack Overflow Community!

EDIT: I have successfully read the first two numbers

I want multiArray to inherit its size from the numbers array.

What is the best way to do this? 
How would I go about this? I read somewhere about const cast, but I don't know if that is a proper way to go about it..

Comment: You shouldn't be using raw arrays. You should be using a `std::vector`. It's just not good to hold things with raw arrays.

Comment: What constraints did the teacher place on your project? Are you allowed to use STL, does it have to be a certain style, etc...

Comment: I've read that also, but my teacher does not want us to be using more advanced methods as he says.. He just wants us to use basic stuff we've already learned.. file-io, arrays, barely learned multidimensional arrays, and functions @VermillionAzure , I appreciate the help!

Comment: @JohnSmith First of all, you need to dynamically allocate the array. Simply putting slapping a pointer onto the array will not make it dynamic. If you cannot dynamically allocate it, ask for upper and lower bounds on the array dimensions.

Comment: I would ask your teacher for assistance... You will need to look at reading the first two lines, and then declaring the necessary data structure to contain the information from the remainder of the file. Stack Overflow isn't really the best place for homework questions, and none of us know the actual specifications of the assignment to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Rootix I'm assuming we can use STL as we have used bitset before and he said we can only use things we have already learned as bitset is part of STL I'd hope so.. but he is saying use it to a minimal if possible, no certain style but all the inputs are from that one file

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I will message him and see what he has to say. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to be of assistance, good luck :)

Comment: @Rootix I asked him for assistance and he sent me a link to SO with basically the same answer as Mi_Onim. Now my next problem I'm running into is how to skip the first line with using getline() the read the file into the array.

Comment: @JohnSmith Take a look at utilizing count to skip the first line. That would likely be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically allocate memory for your multiArray. A dynamic 2-dimensional array is an array of pointers to arrays. You should initialize it using a loop:

```
    int** multiArray = new int*[numbers[0]];
    for (int i =0; i <numbers[0]; i++)
        multiArray[i] = new int[numbers[1]];
```

Comment: Thank you, now as to my second part, I have been reading on here on how to input a file into the 2d array which I don't think I have a problem with. I've read to use getline() as the file that I have is organized in a way that would work. but how could I skip the first line as I have already used it for the array numbers[] ? Thanks again!

Comment: Instead of _inputFile >> numbers[count]_ you can read the first line using getline(), so that the next time you will call getline(), it will start reading from the second line. There is another way to ignore the first line: read about istream::ignore in any C++ reference guide.